# How to split a long row by specific range and add it as a new rows - Excel

Tags: excel

Currently, I have pulled a dataset in .csv format which has import and export data.
The data is provided by country -> Goods and their value.
The issue is the data is given as a section, which is in long row format for example.

```
Country1                       Country 2                      Country 255   
Meat | Vegetables | oil | .... Meat | Vegetables | oil | .... Meat | Vegetables | oil | ....  
8    | 6          | 4   | ....  18  | 62       | 24    | ....  18  | 62       | 24    | ....
```

[image]

What I am expecting is meat, vegetable and other 54 categories values should come as a next row for each 255 countries. So that I can transpose the country name and which can look like below

```
         Meat | Vegetable | Oil | ....... |flowers|
Country1 8    | 6         | 4   | ....... | 2     |
Country2 18   | 62        | 24  | ....... | 2     |
.
.
.
Country255 18 | 62        | 24  | ....... | 2     |
```

[image]

Please let me know if any more clarification is required.

Comment: Is there no better way to pull the data as a better shape?

Comment: Agree with @Isolated. This is a terrible data format. What kind of source produces that? Look into Power Query to clean it up, but it will be a big effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you cannot modify the data pull, then maybe it's not so terrible as long as the following are met: (1) Each country has the same number of categories, and; (2) Categories are indeed delimited with bar or something else. If that's the case, then I would do this:

1. Import the data into excel and delimit (text to columns) the specified character in the csv. Let's assume row1 is country, row2 is category, and row3 is volume.
2. Copy rows 1, 2 and 3 then transpose your data (paste option) into another sheet. Now everything is vertical.
3. Determine best way to fill in the missing country names. If they each start where the first category starts, then you could double-click down (but need to do this 255 times). Probably other ways to do this.
4. Create a pivot off your data.

[image]

But again, if countries have different number of categories, then it's not so simple and some other method may be needed.